# Git svn fetch restarts from 0 at each branch point

Tags: fetch, git-svn, revision

I am trying to clone the last 2 years of history from an SVN repository.
I specified in the git svn init that I only wanted to get revisions from 5000 to HEAD (using -r5000:HEAD) and followed with git svn fetch.
But this command regularly stop with random errors which i found the only solution is to continue the fetch by relaunching git svn fetch.
The problem I have is this. If I use git svn fetch without specifying a range of revisions, it continues from last fetched revision but everytime it finds a new branching point, it restarts the fetch of this branching point from revision 0 instead of 5000.

So I tried specifying the range 5000:HEAD with the git svn fetch but in that case it restarts from revision 5000 even though it was already at revision 8000.
Is there something I can do to actually restart the fetch from the last revision fetched while still restarting from revision 5000 when it finds a new branch point ?
Thanks for your help